# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when loading the page with the paypal ipn

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal-ipn

I'm working with the paypal ipn integrated in my asp page , everything worked perfectly when I was using the sandbox url, when I was accessing the page with the ipn , the page was loaded normally without any errors but when I've changed the post url in the ipn process , now when I'm opening the page in the browser I get the following error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm worried and confused... if someone will send a payment , will the ipn page works? 
Is this error because when I load it , it tries to post data to paypal but since there's no data..it tells me object reference ....

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string postUrl = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);

            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
            string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
            string ipnPost = strRequest;
            strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
            req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;


            StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(),
            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            streamOut.Write(strRequest);
            streamOut.Close();

            StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            streamIn.Close();


            if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
            {
                  //some checking
            }
             else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
            {
                //some code 
            }
            else
              {
               }
}
```

Comment: Definitely going to need some code to help you.

Comment: Used this code : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers , it worked perfect but the only thing I've changed was the post url..and I get that error

Comment: So you'd like me to read through that entire projects-worth of code, figure out what it does, why it doesn't work for you, without you being willing to at least narrow it down to which code snippet makes the call?  All for some e-points on a website?  Help me help you!

Comment: Now we're cooking.  Put in a breakpoint and run your code.  Which line throws the object reference error?

Comment: Sorry post updated, wired thing is that in tells me in the Stack trace , the erros is in the block of the strResponse == Invalid . but i'm there just checking if the mysql connection is opened -> close

Comment: Most likely because streamIn is null.  Run your code, and see.  Most likely because the req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream() isn't returning anything.

Comment: ah ..there was an error when checking if the mysqlconn is open . Thanks for you help :)